# jQuery multiple getElementByID

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, foreach

i have a problem with showing popout window. I have 2 popout windows. They are generated through php foreach (in echo)... The problem is, every time is gonna show only the FIRST span on the page, but that SECOND doesn't work. PHP code here:

```
echo __( "<div class='action' style='margin-bottom: -20px'>
            <div id='box' style='background-color:". $active_row->color .";width: 10px;height:10px;float:left;margin:5px 10px 0px 10px;'> </div>
            <span id='myBtn' style='color:orange'> ". $active_row->title ."<span id='GoogleADD' style='float:right; color:orange; text-decoration:underline'> Add </span> </span> <span id='end' style='float:right; margin-right: 10px'>". $endDateString ."</span> <span style='float:right'>  -  </span> <span id='start' style='float:right; margin-left:10px'> ". $newDateString ." </div> <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->

            <!-- The Modal -->
            <div id='myModal' class='modal'>

              <!-- Modal content -->
              <div class='modal-content'>
                <div class='modal-header'>
                  <span class='close'>×</span>
                  <h2 style='text-align:center'>Podrobnosti o akci</h2>
                </div>
                <div class='modal-body'>
                  <p> Název akce: <b>". $active_row->title ."</b> </p>
                  <p> Podrobnosti: <b>". $active_row->description ." </b> </p>
                  <p> Začátek akce: <b>". $newDateString ." </b> </p>
                  <p> Konec akce: <b>". $endDateString ." </b> </p>
                  <p> Přidat akci do vašeho Google Kalendáře: <b style='color: orange; text-decoration: underline'> ADD ME! </b> </p> 
                </div>
                <div class='modal-footer'></div>
              </div>
            </div>");
```

Then I have a script, where i want to show them, when someone click on them. I am checking the ID on "third" row here (span id="myBtn").

Here is my jQuery script.

```
<script>
                        // Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById('myBtn');

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName('close')[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = 'block';
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = 'none';
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = 'none';
    }
}


    </script>"
```

Can you help me out please ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The "id" attribute should be unique - having two or more elements with the same id is a mistake.

Comment: What @Pointy said - if you use classes, you can use `getElementsByClassName()`

Comment: I tried but I couldn't do an unique id...

Comment: that's not jquery. that's just javascript. if you were using jquery, you'd be using `$('#myModal)` instead of typing out the full `getWhatever()` function names.

Comment: Well, you're not doing a unique id this way either. You can use the next() or closest() jquery functions maybe?

Comment: @Stacker I did right now, but then it doesn't work, nothing shows up even the first span. I did that classes

Comment: Would you be able to simplify it down to a jsfiddle?

Comment: @Stacker Uhh I don't even know what is jsfiddle so probably not, but i'll try my best.

Comment: Saying you couldn't do a unique ID means either (a) you need to find a way; or (b) you need to use something other than ID. Two duplicate IDs violate w3c standards--for good reason.

Comment: @JanKocvik Use [stack snippets](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270944/feedback-requested-stack-snippets-2-0) to put an executable example directly in the question.

Comment: @Stacker I did that jsfiddle, link here:

https://jsfiddle.net/n2phxhh8/5/#&togetherjs=CNJzSUrtB6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will help you to achieve your goal. I have removed some unwanted details from your example, and try to keep it as simple as possible.

```
<div class='action' >
    <span class="MyBtn" rel="myModal1" style='color:orange'>Title 1</span>
</div> 
<!-- The Modal 1 -->
<div id='myModal1' class='modal' style="display:none">
    <!-- Modal content 1 -->
    <div class='modal-content'>
        <div class='modal-header'>
            <span class='close'  rel="myModal1"  >X</span>
            <h2 style='text-align:center'>Popup 1 header</h2>
        </div>
        <div class='modal-body'>'Popup 1 content goes here...'</div>
        <div class='modal-footer'></div>
    </div>
</div>



<div class='action' >
    <span class="MyBtn" rel="myModal2" style='color:orange'>Title 2</span>
</div> 
<!-- The Modal 2 -->
<div id='myModal2' class='modal' style="display:none">
    <!-- Modal content 2-->
    <div class='modal-content'>
        <div class='modal-header'>
            <span class='close'  rel="myModal2" >X</span>
            <h2 style='text-align:center'>Popup 2 header</h2>
        </div>
        <div class='modal-body'>'Popup 2 content goes here...'</div>
        <div class='modal-footer'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above html portion can be generated with the help of any looping structure. Please notice that I have write the id of the modal container in *rel* attribute at two different places.

1. In the *span* tag with MyBtn class.
2. In the *span* tag with close class.

You need to generate the unique id for your modal cotainer and also should be written there. *(You can use $active_row->ID, insted of the serial number)*

Here is the script, which will open and close the modal box.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var button_click = function() {
        var ModalID = this.getAttribute("rel");
        document.getElementById(ModalID).style.display = 'block';
    };

    var close_click = function() {
        var ModalID = this.getAttribute("rel");
        document.getElementById(ModalID).style.display = 'none';
    };


    // Get the button that opens the modal
    var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('MyBtn');

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var close = document.getElementsByClassName('close') ;

    // Assign the events to the buttons (open & close)
    for(iCount = 0; iCount < btn.length; iCount++) {
        btn[iCount].addEventListener('click', button_click, false) ;
        close[iCount].addEventListener('click', close_click, false) ;
    }
</script>
```

I wish it will help enough.

Have a great time.